# Slurm job producing mysterious string of colons when using more

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, slurm

I am trying to run some bioinformatics software on a set of files, but the tool fails unexpectedly when I submit it with slurm, apparently due to improper delivery of the input file lists. If I run it on the command line, it seems to work. I've substituted some toy file names below because the actual names are very long. The tool is called rMATs but the tool itself is irrelevant to my issue.

I use an .sbatch file to submit the job to the cluster from the command line like so:

```
sbatch job.sbatch group1.txt group2.txt
```

Where the two text files contain a comma separated list of data files. Within the .sbatch file, I pass the variables to the bioinformatics tool like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --time=00:00:20
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH -o ./o.%j
#SBATCH --err ./e.%j
#SBATCH --account=owner-guest
#SBATCH --partition=server-guest

bioinfotool.py -arg1 `more group1.txt` -arg2 `more group2.txt`
```

I am doing it this way because the bioinformatics tool is apparently unable to parse the text file directly.

However, it still does not work and I think it is due to my use of backticks and the more command. I try to debug by adding an echo statement

```
echo `more group1.txt`
```

The output should be

```
sample1.bam,sample2.bam,sample3.bam
```

however, the actual output is

```
:::::::::::::: group1.txt :::::::::::::: sample1.bam,sample2.bam,sample3.bam
```

Thus, it appears to me that this inexplicable comma string + file name + comma string is being prepended to my list of files before it is passed to the bioinformatics tool.

Googling things like '"string of commas" + slurm' has been fruitless so I am resorting to posting my own question.

Where are these commas coming from? Is there a better way to extract the file name string from the txt file?

Thanks

Edit: Using 'cat' instead of 'more' solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`more` is an interactive program, and the colons you are seeing are likely the colon `more` uses to show it expects user input.

If you just want to dump the file contents, `cat` is what you need:.

```
bioinfotool.py -arg1 `cat group1.txt` -arg2 `cat group2.txt`
```

You can also run this directly from the terminal, `cat group1.txt`, to see you get what you expect.

Note in Bourne shells like Bash you can `$(cat group1.txt) instead of using backticks, which allows for nesting and some more options, but it should not matter in your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I had forgotten about the interactive feature of `more`  because my text file is only a few lines. Any idea why this is only occurring within the context of slurm and not from the command line?

Comment: @user7474117 No problem, you are welcome. Note in SO no need for a thank you comment, but a +1 (the up arrow) is always appreciated.